# SQL Server 2008 - split time intervals given by StartTime, EndTime at selected points

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table containing time intervals in the form of columns StartTime, EndTime. The table also contains some other identifiers. The first 3 rows of this table look like this:

```
create table #ExampleTable (ID int, PRDATE date, RID int, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime); 
INSERT INTO #ExampleTable(ID, PRDATE, RID, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES  
(10000422,'2014-09-01',6,'2014-09-01 04:08:15.000','2014-09-01 04:13:13.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 04:08:23.000','2014-09-01 09:44:47.000'),
(20000432,'2014-09-01',116,'2014-09-01 04:08:51.000','2014-09-01 05:07:38.000');
```

I would like to split the intervals at the SplitPoints given in other table #SplitPoints,

```
create table #SplitPoints (SplitPoint DateTime); 
INSERT INTO #SplitPoints(SplitPoint) VALUES 
('2014-09-01 04:15:00.000'),
('2014-09-01 04:45:00.000'),
('2014-09-01 05:30:00.000');
```

creating new rows when appropriate. The desired result looks like

```
create table #DesiredResult (ID int, PRDATE date, RID int, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime); 
INSERT INTO #DesiredResult(ID, PRDATE, RID, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES 
(10000422,'2014-09-01',6,'2014-09-01 04:08:15.000','2014-09-01 04:13:13.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 04:08:23.000','2014-09-01 04:15:00.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 04:15:00.000','2014-09-01 04:45:00.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 04:45:00.000','2014-09-01 05:30:00.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 05:30:00.000','2014-09-01 09:44:47.000'),
(20000432,'2014-09-01',116,'2014-09-01 04:08:51.000','2014-09-01 04:15:00.000'),
(20000432,'2014-09-01',116,'2014-09-01 04:15:00.000','2014-09-01 04:45:00.000'),
(20000432,'2014-09-01',116,'2014-09-01 04:45:00.000','2014-09-01 05:07:38.000');
```

How can I accomlish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make the example data:

```
DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE (ID int, PRDATE date, RID int, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime); 
INSERT INTO @ExampleTable(ID, PRDATE, RID, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES  
(10000422,'2014-09-01',6,'2014-09-01 04:08:15.000','2014-09-01 04:13:13.000'),
(10000457,'2014-09-01',103,'2014-09-01 04:08:23.000','2014-09-01 09:44:47.000'),
(20000432,'2014-09-01',116,'2014-09-01 04:08:51.000','2014-09-01 05:07:38.000'); 

DECLARE @SplitPoints TABLE (SplitPoint DateTime); 
INSERT INTO @SplitPoints(SplitPoint) VALUES 
('2014-09-01 04:15:00.000'),
('2014-09-01 04:45:00.000'),
('2014-09-01 05:30:00.000');
```

Now I make a CTE to get all of the unique dates (both start and end) to order them:

```
;WITH MyDates AS
(
SELECT ID, PRDATE, RID, StartTime
FROM @ExampleTable
UNION
SELECT ID, PRDATE, RID, EndTime
FROM @ExampleTable
UNION
SELECT et.ID, et.PRDATE, et.RID, sp.SplitPoint
FROM @ExampleTable et 
INNER JOIN @SplitPoints sp
    ON sp.SplitPoint >= et.StartTime AND sp.SplitPoint < et.EndTime
)
```

Now lets put the data in order and create the new records, with the preceding record as the start, and the next record as the endtime till we run out of records for each date/rid set.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY PRDATE, RID ORDER BY StartTime) AS EndTime 
    FROM MyDates
) d
WHERE d.EndTime IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the output:

```
ID  PRDATE  RID StartTime   EndTime
10000422    2014-09-01  6   2014-09-01 04:08:15.000 2014-09-01 04:13:13.000
10000457    2014-09-01  103 2014-09-01 04:08:23.000 2014-09-01 04:15:00.000
10000457    2014-09-01  103 2014-09-01 04:15:00.000 2014-09-01 04:45:00.000
10000457    2014-09-01  103 2014-09-01 04:45:00.000 2014-09-01 05:30:00.000
10000457    2014-09-01  103 2014-09-01 05:30:00.000 2014-09-01 09:44:47.000
20000432    2014-09-01  116 2014-09-01 04:08:51.000 2014-09-01 04:15:00.000
20000432    2014-09-01  116 2014-09-01 04:15:00.000 2014-09-01 04:45:00.000
20000432    2014-09-01  116 2014-09-01 04:45:00.000 2014-09-01 05:07:38.000
```

Comment: If I add e.g. (10000422,'2014-09-01',6,'2014-09-01 06:08:15.000','2014-09-01 07:13:13.000') to @ExampleTable, this needs a little modification - adding column "type" 1 (StartTime), 0(EndTime), -1(SplitPoint) to the three select statements an then filtering out those with type 0. But I can use this with a little change, thanks!

Comment: do you expect records with a duplicate ids and rids?

Comment: Yes, those could be expected. But the (ID, StartTime) pair is unique, and the time intervals for given ID do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

By utilizing a UNION SELECT you may be able to accomplish what you are looking for I did a quick and dirty query to show how the dates can be pulled the way I thought you were looking to do this. The trickiest part in this was the Start_Date in the last select because unless you want the logic I put in the query you will need to adjust to fit your needs. I also added a splitstart and splitend time to your table this makes the union possible once again not sure if this is possible for you but thought I would try to help if I could.

```
DECLARE 
    @Start_Date DATETIME = '2014-09-01 04:08:23.000'
    ,@End_Date DATETIME = '2014-09-01 09:44:47.000'

    create table #SplitPoints (SplitPointStart DateTime,SplitPointEnd DateTime); 
    INSERT INTO #SplitPoints(SplitPointStart,SplitPointEnd) VALUES 
    ('2014-09-01 04:15:00.000','2014-09-01 04:45:00.000'),
    ('2014-09-01 04:45:00.000','2014-09-01 05:30:00.000'),
    ('2014-09-01 05:30:00.000','2014-09-01 06:00:00.000');


    SELECT 
            @Start_Date
    ,CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) <= 15 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@Start_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':15.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) <= 30 AND DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) > 15 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@Start_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':30.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) <= 45 AND DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) > 30 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@Start_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':45.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) <= 60 AND DATEPART(m,@Start_Date) > 45 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,DATEADD(hh,1,@Start_Date))AS VARCHAR) + ':00.000' 
    ELSE ''
    END
    UNION
    SELECT
    SplitPointStart,SplitPointEnd
    FROM #Splitpoints
    WHERE 
    SplitPointStart > @Start_Date
    AND SplitPointEnd < @End_Date
    UNION 
    SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,DATEADD(mm,-30,@End_Date)) <= 15 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@End_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':15.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,DATEADD(mm,-30,@End_Date)) <= 30 AND DATEPART(m,@End_Date) > 15 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@End_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':30.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,DATEADD(mm,-30,@End_Date)) <= 45 AND DATEPART(m,@End_Date) > 30 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,@End_Date)AS VARCHAR) + ':45.000' 
    WHEN DATEPART(m,DATEADD(mm,-30,@End_Date)) <= 60 AND DATEPART(m,@End_Date) > 45 THEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)AS VARCHAR) + ' '+ CAST(DATEPART(hh,DATEADD(hh,-1,@End_Date))AS VARCHAR) + ':00.000' 
    ELSE ''
    END
    ,@End_Date

    drop table #SplitPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your required functionality not possible directly from query it need something like looping.

I think below code will help you

```
DECLARE @ID NUMERIC
DECLARE @PRDDate DATE,
        @rid     NUMERIC
DECLARE @starttime DATETIME
DECLARE @endtime DATETIME
DECLARE @SplitPoint DATETIME

CREATE TABLE #desiredresult
  (
     id        INT,
     prdate    DATE,
     rid       INT,
     starttime DATETIME,
     endtime   DATETIME
  )

 -- declare cursor called firstcursor
  DECLARE firstcursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT id,
         prdate,
         rid,
         starttime,
         endtime
  FROM   #exampletable
  ORDER  BY id

-- Open the cursor
OPEN firstcursor

-- Fetch the first row of the cursor and assign its values into variables
FETCH next FROM firstcursor INTO @ID, @PRDDate, @rid, @starttime, @endtime

-- perform action whilst a row was found
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      DECLARE secoundcursor CURSOR FOR
             SELECT splitpoint
                FROM   #splitpoints
                WHERE  splitpoint < @endtime
                ORDER  BY splitpoint
      OPEN secoundcursor      
      -- perform action whilst a row was found
      DECLARE @prev DATETIME
      FETCH next FROM secoundcursor INTO @SplitPoint
      DECLARE @index int = 0
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF( @index =0 )
              BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO #desiredresult
                          (id,
                           prdate,
                           rid,
                           starttime,
                           endtime)
                  VALUES     (@ID,
                          @PRDDate,
                          @rid,
                          @starttime,
                          @SplitPoint)
               END
            ELSE
               BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO #desiredresult
                              (id,
                               prdate,
                               rid,
                               starttime,
                               endtime)
                  VALUES     (@ID,
                              @PRDDate,
                              @rid,
                              @prev,
                              @SplitPoint)
              END

            SET @prev = @SplitPoint
            SET @index = @index + 1
           FETCH next FROM secoundcursor INTO @SplitPoint
        END

      CLOSE secoundcursor

      -- Free memory used by cursor
      DEALLOCATE secoundcursor

      if(@index =0)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #desiredresult
                          (id,
                           prdate,
                           rid,
                           starttime,
                           endtime)
              VALUES     (@ID,
                          @PRDDate,
                          @rid,
                          @starttime,
                          @endtime)
      END
      else
          begin
              INSERT INTO #desiredresult
                          (id,
                           prdate,
                           rid,
                           starttime,
                           endtime)
              VALUES     (@ID,
                          @PRDDate,
                          @rid,
                         @prev,
                          @endtime)
      end

      -- get next row of cursor
      FETCH next FROM firstcursor INTO @ID, @PRDDate, @rid, @starttime, @endtime
   END

 -- Close the cursor to release locks
 CLOSE firstcursor

 -- Free memory used by cursor
 DEALLOCATE firstcursor

 SELECT *
 FROM   #desiredresult
```